# WSO2: In-Line XML entry in register - How to remove namespace

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm new to WSO2 ESB product and I'm trying to local registry entry for store XML messages template. I noted that when I save the resource using the 'Add In-Lined XML Entry', always the synapse namespace is added to the root element.
Is there any method to avoid this ?...alternatively, I can remove it later when I refer to that key in my mediators?
Consider that my aim is to use that reference in enrich mediator.
thanks and regards
fab

Answer (score 9):

You just have to specified `xmlns=""` on the root element inside your xml entry

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but when I save the code into 'Inlined XML entry' editor, the namespace attribute is automatically changed to xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" and my customization is ignored.

Comment: You should edit the file directly from the filesystem, into repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/local-entries

Comment: This is the solution.